# What is the most effective method of storing the value in this string?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java

Currently, I have a Listbox on the page with an associated record count, scenarios would be as follows:

- No Records
- Displaying 1 Record(s)
- Displaying 1-14 of X Records

However when I try `getText()` on this element it returns the above string plus all entries which exist in the listbox, see image:

[image: Web App ListBox/Record Count]

`getText()` returns the record count and every listbox entry for that page in question. e.g:

```
1-15 of 152 Records
\\\
\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\
```

Im making a generic method to return my record count in every scenario, my thought is to grab it and trim the string down by characters and run it through a few if statements to cover every possible scenario as the text can vary quite substantially based on the record count.

Am I mad? is there a much better way to handle this?

[image: Div Code]

Comment: Do you have the code for the listbox?

Comment: What is the code you're using to pull the text?

Comment: I am guessing you are using outer div to get text value. Can you expand div and try to locate just element which shows number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some string manipulations to get the desired result

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.id(idOfRecordCountElement)).getText();
String desiredText=text.substring(0,text.indexOf("\n"));
```